# Не отображается стандартная форма логина, Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security

Проблема заключается в том, что при подключении Spring Security и настройке конфига все запросы так и остались незащищенными, что странно. Не могу понять, проблема в том, что чего-то не доинтегрировал? В логгере никаких проблем не обнаружено с security

**Сам `SecurityConfig`:**

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @Order(1000)
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

final
DataSource dataSource;

public SecurityConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource);

}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/project").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder()
{
    return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
  }
 }
```

**Также `SpringConfig`:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.ahpg.spring")
@EnableWebMvc

public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;


@Autowired
public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
}

@Bean
SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
    return templateEngine;
}
@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
    return new SpringSecurityDialect();
}

@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}

@Override
public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    registry.viewResolver(resolver);
}

public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}

    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler(
            "/img/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/libs/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations(
                    "classpath:/static/img/",
                    "classpath:/static/css/",
                    "classpath:/static/libs/",
                    "classpath:/static/js/",
                    "/webjars/");

}
@Bean
public HikariConfig hikariConfig() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data_db");
    hikariConfig.setUsername("postgres");
    hikariConfig.setPassword("pass");

    return hikariConfig;

 }
}
```

**и `pom.xml`:**

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${ss.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${ss.ver}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${ss.ver}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Простая форма для логина(просто чтоб увидеть, отрабатывает ли security)

```
<head>
 </head>
  <body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form name='f' action="login" method='POST'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Форму логина точно не доконфигурировал.

На форму логина надо добавить адрес и разрешения

```
.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
```

Чтобы запросы были защищёнными надо добавить

```
.anyRequest().authenticated()
```

Comment: изменил метод до вида
`    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/AHPG").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }`

но это не решило проблему, все так же отсутствует форма, при любом запросе.

Comment: Отсутствует форма в вопросе. Переход на страницу логина выполняется?

Comment: да, имеется пустая страница "login", при переходе на нее получаю пустую страницу. Или же нужно обозначить форму вручную?

Comment: Если нет формы логина, то ее надо создавать.

Comment: мне казалось, что с коробки уже имеется простенькая форма. Ну и непонятно, почему тогда без формы все равно имеется доступ к любому url, если, по сути, к ним доступа не должно быть

Comment: А как же `/admin`  или `/project`? И как же тогда происходит переход? Впрочем на свой вопрос я не получил ответа.

Comment: в данный момент у меня только пост-форма с регистрацией  и простая логин-форма, пустая страница /admin тоже имеется. Просто насколько я изучал информацию по security, он вроде должен при себе иметь с 0 форму, но ее я не вижу. По поводу
"отсутствует форма в вопросе" - сейчас добавлю в вопрос.
Впервые с этим работаю, если нужны какие-либо доп.куски кода - дайте знать

Comment: Нет, вопрос был задан: Переход на страницу логина выполняется?

Comment: да, и форма отображается. Но только если вручную /login прописывать, при запросе по другим адресам они открываются без проблем, форма не появляется

Comment: Ещё раз повторяю вопрос: по адресам /admin или /project происходит переход на страницу /login?

Comment: Неа, переходит на /admin без формы

Comment: Это возможно только если пользователь уже залогиниться, и у него есть роль `ADMIN`. Похоже что Spring Security вообще не установлено.

Comment: да, только я не понимаю, что не так

Comment: Нашел решение. При добавлении класса
`SecurityWebInitializer` начала появляться форма